# primitive types / reference types in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have lived under the assumption that there are primitive types and reference types in Javascript. On a day-to-day basis, I've never had this impact me but I was just starting to a lot more JS and wanted to update my 'thinking'. In other words, I would have betted $20 that the following would return 68

```
var my_obj = {};
var tmp_obj = {};

tmp_obj.my_int = 38;
my_obj.tmp_val = tmp_obj.my_int;
tmp_obj.my_int = 68;

alert('68 means reference, 38 means primitve: ' + my_obj.tmp_val);
```

but it returns 38.

[image]

Are all instances of numbers primitive types even if they exist in the context of a reference type? If y, I'm really surprised and find that odd behavior(and would be out $20). Or is my example not demonstrating what I think it is?

thx in advance

**UPDATE #1**

Wow, thx for all the answers. Here's a slight change which helps me a lot in understaning:

```
var my_obj={};
var tmp_obj={};
var my_obj_2=tmp_obj;
tmp_obj.my_int=38;
my_obj.tmp_val=tmp_obj.my_int;
tmp_obj.my_int=68
alert('68 means reference, 38 means primitve: ' + my_obj.tmp_val);   // 38
alert('68 means reference, 38 means primitve: ' + my_obj_2.my_int);  // 68
my_obj_2.my_int=78;
alert(tmp_obj.my_int); // tmp_obj is now 78 ie two way
```

Comment: `my_obj` and `tmp_obj` are two independent objects. Setting the value of a property of one of them won't affect the other object, no matter where the original value came from. It's the same for `var a = 1; var b = a; a = 2;`... `b` will still be `1`.

Comment: Compare with: `tmp_obj = my_obj; tmp_obj.my_int = 68; alert(my_obj.my_int)`.

Comment: @FelixKling ...and regardless of whether or not the property is primitive or reference type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You example would work as expected if you had

```
     my_obj = tmp_obj;
```

Then, all the properties would point to the same reference since there would only be one object.

But when you write

```
     my_obj.tmp_val = tmp_obj.my_int;
```

then `my_obj.tmp_val` will take the value that's stored in `tmp_obj.my_int` but that doesn't create a new reference between the 2 objects.

Comment: this is basically what I didn't understand correctly; thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

If I may use a Java-like syntax, it appears you expected the code to behave like this, where there is an integer object that has its value mutated.

```
tmp_obj.my_int = new Integer(38);
my_obj.tmp_val = tmp_obj.my_int;
tmp_obj.my_int.setValue(68);
```

Since it doesn't print `68` you conclude that integers must be a primitive type not a reference type. That doesn't necessarily follow, though. Consider this alternate interpretation:

```
tmp_obj.my_int = new Integer(38);
my_obj.tmp_val = tmp_obj.my_int;
tmp_obj.my_int = new Integer(68);
```

Here integers are reference types but `my_obj.tmp_val` will still contain the value `38`, because assigning to an integer means overwriting references.

You can think of integers as being immutable objects. JavaScript does a very good job of presenting a unified everything-is-an-object view, so this is a better interpretation of the results than "integers are primitive types".

Comment: It's kind of funny to answer a question about one language with examples from another language, but you bring it to the point. Nice answer +1. (since you cannot even change the value of `Number` objects in JS, there really is no good way to demonstrate this in JS).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that when the assignment operator can only assign the *referent* and not the *referee* of a reference, like in Javascript, Python or Java (but contrary to C++ where pointers can be dereferenced before assignment, e.g., `*p = 3;`), one cannot tell whether primitive types are *[value types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type)* or *[reference types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type)*; only for composite types one can.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, values like numbers and strings work like primitive values. They are immutable. Assigning a new value to a variable replaces the old value, it doesn't change the value that's there.

Example:

```
var x = 42;
var y = x; // y == 42
x = 1337; // this puts a new value in x, it doesn't change 42 to be 1337
alert(y); // it's still 42
```

The same works for strings:

```
var x = "42";
var y = x; // y == "42"
x = "1337"; // this puts a new string in x, it doesn't change "42" to be "1337"
alert(y); // it's still "42"
```

Also if you use object properties;

```
var o = {};
o.x = 42;
o.y = o.x; // o.y == 42
o.x = 1337; // this puts a new value in o.x, it doesn't change 42 to be 1337
alert(o.y); // it's still 42
```

How a value acts only depends on its type, not wether it's stored in a regular variable or in a property in an object.

Even if strings are implemented as an object internally, it's immutable and works as a value. Copying a string may copy a reference to an object, but the effect is that you get a separate copy, because nothing can change the string value itself.

Answer (score 3):

> I have lived under the assumption that there are primitive types and reference types in Javascript.

That's true. The only reference values are objects, though; primitive values are not mutable.

> Are all instances of numbers primitive types even if they exist in the context of a reference type?

Yes. Their context is not relevant.

Comment: Arrays are also references.

Comment: @Barmar: arrays are also objects.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are two key things to understand here:

1. Primitive values are never references
2. JavaScript references can never be assigned to, just copied around.

Considering this code to demonstrate the first point:

```
var a = 10,
    b = a,
    c = {foo : 20}
    d = c.foo;

b = 20;
d = 30;
a;     // 10;
c.foo; // 20;
```

So, you have "slots" (variables or properties) holding primitive values, not references. Changing the value in one of those slots won't affect the others.

Considering the second point:

```
var a = {foo: true},
    b = a;
b.foo; // true
b.foo = false;
a.foo; // false;
b = {bar: false};
a;     // {foo: false}
```

Variable `a` contains an object, and `b` is initially a reference *to the same object*. Assigning to `b.foo` affects `a`, since `b` and `a` are pointing to the exact same object. However, those references are just like any other value stored in a given slot: when you assign something else to the slot, the reference just gets replaced with a different value. So assigning to `b` doesn't affect `a`.

Comment: very good point, I had to read through twice to get subtleties - so assigning can create like a hybrid object where there are parts that are part of the reference and parts that are separate.

Comment: No, I believe my explanation is confusing, I'll reword it. If you try to change `b.foo` *before* assigning something else to `b`, it would affect `a`. But after `b = {bar: false};`, there's no more link between the two objects. There are no hybrid objects.

Comment: ok, so similar to maybe copy-on-write in the UNIX process model.