# Is there a big difference between reference and primitive types of boolean, number etc.?

Tags: javascript

I rad, that we can create numbers as:

> var num = 10;

and:

> var num = new Number(10);

may i use only first variation of declaration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [primitive types / reference types in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443357/primitive-types-reference-types-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the first one *always*, as it returns a primitive value.

The second method *looks* like it returns a primitive value but it doesn't. Infact, it returns an object with a boxed primitive value.

To explain this, lets declare two variables:

```
var a = 2;
var b = new Number(2);
```

The expression `a == b` will return true since JavaScript *coerces* `b` to a primitive value of 2. However, the expression `a === b` will return false as the types are different: `a` being a primitive and `b` being an object.

Comment: Exactly. The following demonstrates:

var num = 10;
typeof num;
"number"

var num = new Number(10);
typeof num;
"object"

Comment: yes,  i am new in js so it takes my head away when i ma trying to understand both.so,1st var is better to use?

Comment: not 'better' but correct way to use it. See my edit to understand the difference.

Comment: got it,thanks.Same situation with strings, booleans...?

Comment: I would say, yes in general avoid new operator. I use it sparingly myself like for declaring a new date etc. But yes, I never use 'new' for primitives.

Comment: Sure, happy to help :)

Comment: Why does `var a = 10;a.toString();` work and not `10.toString()`? What is the difference?

Comment: Found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4046367/3951400) :-) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hey, can you please accept the answer IF you found it correct?